# WPF: TextBox with ProgressBar

Tags: wpf, textbox, progress-bar

Is it possible in WPF to embed a ProgressBar in the Background of a TextBox?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, but there are varying levels of integration you could achieve.

The simplest way would be to host a `ProgressBar` and `TextBox` with see-through background in the same `Grid`:

```
<Grid>
    <ProgressBar/>
    <TextBox Background="#00ffffff"/>
</Grid>
```

Importantly, the background color is transparent but visible to hit testing. #00000000 would not work as expected because clicking on the `TextBox` would actually be clicking on the `ProgressBar`.

You could also retemplate the `TextBox` to incorporate the `ProgressBar` more intrinsically into its template. However, this would be of limited use unless you wrote your own control while you're at it.